# how can I create a ButtonBar for following specific actions

Tags: button

I have two sets of parameters `p1[i] and p2[i], (i=ag, cs, wh)` for which I want to create two separate button bars. I have the following conditions:

Given two equations:

```
 Manipulate[
 ...
 gr[i]=xx*p1[i];
 mu[i]=yy*p2[i];
 p1[i]={0,1};
 p2[i]={0,1};
 ...
 ]
```

Define a scenario such as: `{p1[ag]=1, p1[cs]=1, p1[wh]=0} and {p2[ag]=1, p2[cs]=0, p2[wh]=0}`. Underneath each buton I like to see the choice: `0` or `1`. If it starts with `0`, then clicking on the button should turn it to `1` and vice versa.

With this button format, I want to follow the parameter choices made (i.e., the type of scenario) and obtain the associated values of the two equations, `gr[i], mu[i]`. I want to do this using `Manipulate`.

For me, it is important to see the choices {0,1} made underneath each button as it will help me see the parameter choices.

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

**UPDATE**

For better visualizing the design of `ButtonBar` I wanted, I like to give the picture of the design:

[image]

For parameter set `p1[i]` I have three choices and the same for `p2[i]`. I should be clicking on the values `{0,1}` and the clicked ones should turn to "Green". Note that `ag, cs, wh` remain unchanged for both parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to lay out a table of buttons that show their values and which of the values is currently set. It also shows a second table which displays the results of changing parameter values with the buttons. I use `TableForm` to do the layout because it's easy to use and adequate for purposes of answering this question. You can get a fancier and better looking layout if you are willing mess around with `Grid`.

```
btnLbl = SetterBar[#, {0, 1}] &;

With[{xx = π, yy = E},
  DynamicModule[{tags, gr, mu, p1, p2},
    gr[i_] := xx p1[i];
    mu[i_] := yy p2[i];
    tags = {ag, cs, wh};
    Set[p1[#], 0] & /@ tags;
    Set[p2[#], 0] & /@ tags;
    Column[
      {Dynamic[
         TableForm[
           {Button[btnLbl[p1[#]], p1[#] = Mod[p1[#] + 1, 2], 
              Appearance -> None] & /@ tags,
            Button[btnLbl[p2[#]], p2[#] = Mod[p2[#] + 1, 2], 
              Appearance -> None] & /@ tags},
           TableHeadings -> {{"p1", "p2"}, tags}]],
       Spacer[36],
       Dynamic[
         TableForm[{{gr /@ tags, mu /@ tags},
           TableHeadings -> {{"gr", "mu"}, tags}]]}]]]
```

[image: layout]

Comment: Very nice. With the separate table forms, the buttons look even nicer.

Comment: In my version of `Mathematica 11`, I cannot see the blue colored buttons. Is there a way to set Green color manually?

Comment: @TugrulTemel. As far as I know the color is set by the operating system. I run Mathematica on MacOS where the highlight color is controlled by a setting in System Preferences > General > Appearance. The choices are Blue and Graphite.

Comment: Your above answer solved the question. Since my problem was much wider than what my question implies, I tried to solve the rest of my problem by myself by playing around your `Code`. However, I failed to solve my problem. The rest of my problem is not worth to ask a new question because it is just one step away from the answer. Would it be appropriate for me to update my question again for an extension to your `Code`? I would appreciate if you guide me. thanks.

Comment: @TugrulTemel. Yes, it would be entirely appropriate for you to add an update to question to seek further assistance. I do ask that you insert the code you are working with, so I and others can see how you modified my code. Please insert the code in a form that can be copied and pasted into Mathematica, so that others can use it as a basis for experiments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I put the `Code` as a different question. I think it is already in the list of questions. I just copied and pasted the Code from my notebook, and I hope it would appear in the format you asked for.